# How can hide mat-sidenav of angular flex-layout by default in responsive

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working angular flex-layout and sidenav.  The sidenav is opened in desktop.  I want the sidenav is hidden when the screen < 992px.

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS media query class and set the class for the `mat-sidenav` element.

Comment: If I use CSS the mat-sidenav disappears and I need to keep the hamburger button, I need to close in responsive and opened by default in desktop